# trying to implement stripe "AttributeError: sources"

Tags: reactjs, django

i am getting an error when submiting Credit Card information Saying ("AttributeError at /API/CheckOut/" sources) i think it's comming from here but i don't know what the problem is

views.py

```
class PaymentView(APIView):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    token = request.data.get('stripeToken')

    if userprofile.stripe_customer_id != '' and userprofile.stripe_customer_id is not None:
        customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(
            userprofile.stripe_customer_id)
        customer.sources.create(source=token)

    else:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email=self.request.user.email,
        )
        customer.sources.create(source=token)
        userprofile.stripe_customer_id = customer['id']
        userprofile.one_click_purchasing = True
        userprofile.save()
```

i am using React on the frontend and Posting the Token like this

```
const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: 'card',
  card: cardElement,
});
const stoken=paymentMethod.id
    if (error) {
      seterror(error)
      setloading(false);
    } else {
      seterror(null)
      axios
        .post(checkoutURL, {
          stoken,
          selectedBillingAddress,
          selectedShippingAddress
          
        })
```